# Add activity to multiple feeds?

Tags: laravel, getstream-io

I a post for a user like so...

```
 auth()->user()->posts()->create([
            'title' => 'test title',
            'body' => 'test body',
        ]);
```

This then appears in the user's feed.

But how can I also have this appear in a generic posts feed for all users? I think it needs to be copied across to the posts feed, and I've seen you can use this on your model:

```
public function activityNotify()
{
}
```

But how can I add it to the posts feed as well as a users feed?

Comment: The code you have written is used to store data to the Database. It will be available on all feeds if the required condition matches. You just have to re-retrieve it from the DB.

Comment: @Jerry555555 im not sure what you mean? How can I post the data to multiple feeds on stream.io?